# Reference in the same style for section and appendix

Tags: cross-referencing, appendices, ref

I have a small macro when referencing a section/appendix:

```
\newcommand{\secref}[1]{Sec.~\ref{#1}}
```

Now, when referencing a section, it works just fine and puts something like `Sec. 2.5`. When referencing an appendix, however, it puts `Sec. Appendix A`.

How does LaTeX decide whether it puts just the number (in the case of sections), or whether it puts `Appendix` *and* the "number" `A`? How can I influence this? How can I achieve a reference macro that automatically puts Sec./App./Chap. as appropriate?

Comment: We would need to see a code to tell. That being said, why don't you simply load `cleveref` which adds the type of reference, and is customisable?

Comment: @Bernard: `cleveref` seems to be a good solution in general, but there still remains the question how `\ref` decides what it prints.

Comment: This can be coded in a `clever.cfg` file. This being said, the case of `appendix` is probably trickier and probably require  using the `appendix`  and `apptools` packages.